# Calling a JS function with HTML form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm having trouble getting a javascript function to run on the data from  an html form.
I have this form in HTML:

```
<form id = "form1" onSubmit="getFormObj('form1')">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="First"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Last"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="johndoe@email.com"><br>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="Phone Number"><br>
<input id="button1" type="submit" value="Create Patient">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(PatientLabel);
</script>
```

The submit button is hooked up to a JavaScript function in JQuery:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    createpatient(this);
});
```

The Javascript function I'm trying to run stores the form data to an object and then sets PatientLabel to one of the object's values:

```
var patientdata = {};
var PatientLabel = "";

function createpatient(formId) {
//Turn form data into array data.
    var inputs = $('#'+formId).serializeArray();
    $.each(inputs, function (i, input) {
        patientdata[input.name] = input.value;
    });

//If we got this far, print an example
    patientLabel = patientdata["FirstName"];
}
```

However, when I run this code, the HTML Script that's supposed to print patientLabel doesn't show anything! Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Well, `this` that you pass in refers to the element being clicked - so using `$('#'+formId)` doesn't really make much sense. Is there any error in the console?

Comment: looks like this might be running before the DOM is loaded up. Also, you might need to preventDefault behavior on the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Change As You Like</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='rename.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <form id='form1' name='form1'>
    <label id='firstNameLabel' for='firstName'>First Name&#058; </label><input type='text' id='FirstName' name='firstName' value='First' />
    <label id='lastNameLabel' for='lastName'>Last Name&#058; </label><input type='text' id='lastName' name='lastName' value='Last' />
    <label id='emailLabel' for='email'>email&#058; </label><input type='text' id='email' name='email' value='johndoe&#064;email.com' />
    <label id='phoneNumberLabel' for='phoneNumber'>phone&#058; </label><input type='text' id='phoneNumber' name='phoneNumber' value='&#040;555&#041;555&#045;5555' />
    <input type='submit' id='button1' name='button1' value='Create Patient' />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now on `rename.js`:

```
$(function(){
function createPatient(formElement) {
  var patientData = {}, inputs = formElement.serializeArray();
  $.each(inputs, function(i, o){
    patientData[o.name] = o.value;
  });
  console.log(patientData.firstName);
  // in FireBug could see Object like: console.log(patientData);
}
$('#form1').submit(function(){
  // run other functions here
  createPatient($(this));
  return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I revised the code you suggested, both to $('#form1')...createpatient(this); and createpatient('form1'); in separate instances. Neither printed the inputted name to the page, unfortunately. Then I changed the JQuery from being attached to form1 to being attached to button1, so that it would run on the button being pressed. No dice.

Comment: `patientLabel` is not the same as `PatientLabel` in JavaScript, and since you are running an Event you should do `console.log(patientLabel);` inside your Event handling function. The way you are trying to do it you are attempting to get `""`, because that is `patientLabel`s value before the Event. You might as well scope those higher level variables inside there too. Also, use external JavaScript and never use `document.write()`.

Comment: I changed an instance of 'patientLabel' to 'PatientLabel' and moved all the functionality (from scoping to console.log) inside of the createpatient function. When I run the code I don't get anything in the console log.

Comment: I'll give an example called `Final Example`.

Answer (score -1):

You might change the way you call your function. Try this code if this will help `createpatient($(this).attr('id'));`

Comment: I changed the JQuery to createpatient($(this).attr('id')); and also directly to createpatient("form1"); but neither had any different result.

Comment: That would be the button id.